# Allocating a variable number of objects on the stack in C++

Tags: c++, stack, allocation, dynamic-allocation

I'd like to know if there is a standard way to allocate a variable number of objects on the stack that all today's C++ compilers support. Supposing I have a class `Foo` with a non-trivial public constructor that takes 0 arguments and I want to allocate 10 instances of this class on the heap, then I could use the operator `new[]` in C++ like this:

```
function doSomething() {
    Foo * foos = new Foo[10];
    ...
}
```

If the number of objects to allocate is not known at compile time, I could still use the operator `new[]` in a similar fashion:

```
function doSomething(size_t count) {
    Foo * foos = new Foo[count];
    ...
}
```

So, if I decide to allocate 10 instances of my class on the stack rather than on the heap, I'd use a regular array definition:

```
function doSomething() {
    Foo array[10];
    Foo * foos = array;
    ...
}
```

or probably just `Foo foos[10];` in case I don't need to reassign `foos` later, ok.

Now, if the number of objects I want to allocate on the stack is only known at runtime, I use... what? The only way I can think of to dynamically allocate contiguous memory on the stack is calling the non-standard intrinsic function `alloca`, but I don't know what to do with objects that need initialization.

Comment: _' I use... what?'_ At least GCC supports using `Foo array[n];`, where `n` is a local variable, parameter, class member, what ever ...

Comment: If I can share this... http://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/2809095

Comment: Did you mean to say "stack" in the early part of your last paragraph instead of "heap"?

Comment: @g-makulik thanks, I think that's a non standard feature though, probably not supported by all compilers.

Comment: @GOTO0 Yes, this isn't a standard feature but will be supported by the majority of C/C++ compilers. There might be exotic ones, you'll need to use with very special MCUs. But in general you can consider this will work correctly.

Comment: The short answer to the only real question asked in this entire thing is: No, there isn't. What you want is a VLA in C++. VLA's and their inherent dangers were so well-loved by the C community they're likely being banned from future C's, so don't expect them anytime soon in C++. [A related question you might find interesting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/variable-length-arrays-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
std::vector<MyObject> myObjects;

int runtimeCalculatedSize = sophisticatedRuntimeSizeCalculationMethod();

myObjects.resize(runtimeCalculatedSize,MyObject());
```

Comment: Vector elements are allocated on the heap, not on the stack.

Comment: @GOTO0 Yup! You're right. Sorry I didn't take that aspect of your question in account primarily. What are your particular reasons, you don't wan to allocate objects on the heap? Lacking a suitable `new`/`delete` implementation for your environment?

Comment: Just curiosity actually. `new` and `delete` should be supported on all platforms.

Comment: @GOTO0 _'new and delete should be supported on all platforms.'_ No! Way off NO! I'm developing embedded firmware that won't be able to use heap allocation (`new`/`delete`) at all. I'm using `std::array` for known or compile time calculatable sizes, but _ehhm_, 'non portable' dynamic stack allocation as well. I'm not sure if this isn't even guaranteed by [tag:c++] standards, but not in general for usage with [tag:c].

Comment: @GOTO0 So BTW, what are your (real) portability requirements then? Elaborate in your question ...

Comment: Ok, what I'm actually looking for is a standard compliant solution. I updated my question to put it clear.

Comment: @GOTO0 So OK! You're claiming restictions but don't elaborate why these should be really needed. Whenever you can rely on an environment supporting heap based allocation, what exactly restricts you not to use it?

Comment: Addition: If your standards' claim to have 'new/delete' guaranteed, what's your point about restricting memory association to the stackk??

Comment: The point of the question is not to solve a real or hypothetical design problem but to get a better understanding of the C++ features. As for the `new` and delete `operators`, they are well defined in the current specification (paragraph 5.3.4 and 5.3.5), so any compliant compiler should support them.

Comment: @GOTO0 Fine! So what makes you bothering about the `std::vector` approach then?? Really, thoroughly! Feed with arguments and stuff!! (BTW: It's not about the compiler that supports `new`/`delete` by means of keywords accepted, but what the actual C++ runtime supports).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if lazy, and not worried about portability, I use: Foo array[n]; 
This is standard C code, but has been removed from the C++ standard. But since most compilers do both, most compilers have it.
The canonical way is to declare a std::vector of your type of the desired length.

```
std::vector<Foo> foos(count);
```

But, doing that won't strictly put the data on the stack, is there any reason why using the stack is important to you?